# django socialregistration authentication errors

Tags: python, django, facebook, socialregistration

I am trying to integrate my website to facebook and started with django-socialregistration. All goes fine when i add

```
{% load facebook %}
{% facebook_button %}
```

Now when I click the facebook button from browser, I am redirected to `mysite.com/social/facebook/redirect/` I get the following error:

```
<socialregistration.contrib.facebook.client.Facebook object at 0x2b31a10> is not JSON serializable
```

I don't know why I get this error. And when I tried including `{% facebook_js %}` after the `facebook_button` tag, i get an invalid tag error for facebook_js.

In my settings.py,

```
FACEBOOK_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 'email'
```

I just want the email of the facebook id. What is it that I have to do? Even if this error clears, how do i retrive the email from the returned object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error at last. Had to add this line to my settings.py

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```